# Listitml - dataset

Tags: dataset, listitem

Is it possible to convert listItemcollection to dataset?  Could you please give asp.net code for it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer of this question might help you.

[Convert IEnumerable to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253725/convert-ienumerable-to-datatable)