# Linq to DataSet - Handling Null Values

Tags: asp.net, linq, datatable

I have a requirement to convert LINQ to DataTable.

I stole the following Extension Method from StackOverflow:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            var tb = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
            PropertyInfo[] props = 
            typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public
                                  | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            }

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[props.Length];
                for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }

                tb.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return tb;
  }
```

When the table contains null values it throws exception.
(i.e)

```
DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>
```

**Comission (Decimal type)  column  contains null value)**

at

```
tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a pimped version:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) { 
    DataTable table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); 

    foreach (var prop in props) {
        Type propType = prop.PropertyType;

        // Is it a nullable type? Get the underlying type
        if (propType.IsGenericType && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
            propType = new NullableConverter(propType).UnderlyingType; 

        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, propType);
    } 

    foreach (var item in items) { 
        var values = new object[props.Length]; 
        for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);  

        table.Rows.Add(values); 
    }

    return table;
}
```

**Edit**: Modified my code a bit, tested it, it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could check for null, and then store [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) as the value instead.  There is an [MSDN article about null values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172138%28VS.80%29.aspx), that specifically calls out the lack of support for Nullable<> by Datasets.

Where you have

```
values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
```

make it

```
var value = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
values[i] = value ?? ((object)DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: You could also use the nullable opperator ?? so the code would be `values[i] = value ?? (object)DBNull.Value;`