# Returning a DataTable using Entity Framework ExecuteStoreQuery

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, code-first, ef-code-first

I am working with a system that has many stored procedures that need to be displayed. Creating entities for each of my objects is not practical.

Is it possible and how would I return a `DataTable` using `ExecuteStoreQuery` ?

```
public ObjectResult<DataTable> MethodName(string fileSetName) {
using (var dataContext = new DataContext(_connectionString))
{
var returnDataTable = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dataContext).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<DataTable>("SP_NAME","SP_PARAM");
return returnDataTable;
}
```

Comment: Related: Get a DataTable from a regular EF query (an IEnumerable): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253725/convert-ienumerable-to-datatable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, I don't think that'll work - Entity Framework is geared towards returning **entities** and isn't meant to return `DataTable` objects.

If you need `DataTable` objects, use straight ADO.NET instead.

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework and you just need to run an odd query that doesn't match any entity, you can do so through the context Database property. That gets you to the ADO.NET layer. Some of the other answers reflect this.

Answer (score 18):

Yes it's possible, but it should be used for just dynamic result-set or raw SQL.

```
public DataTable ExecuteStoreQuery(string commandText, params Object[] parameters)
{
    DataTable retVal = new DataTable();
    retVal = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<DataTable>(commandText, parameters).FirstOrDefault();
    return retVal;
}
```

Edit: It's better to use classical ADO.NET to get the data model rather than using Entity Framework because most probably you cannot use `DataTable` even if you can run the method: `context.ExecuteStoreQuery<DataTable>(commandText, parameters).FirstOrDefault();`

ADO.NET Example:

```
public DataSet GetResultReport(int questionId)
{
    DataSet retVal = new DataSet();
    EntityConnection entityConn = (EntityConnection)context.Connection;
    SqlConnection sqlConn = (SqlConnection)entityConn.StoreConnection;
    SqlCommand cmdReport = new SqlCommand([YourSpName], sqlConn);
    SqlDataAdapter daReport = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdReport);
    using (cmdReport)
    {
        SqlParameter questionIdPrm = new SqlParameter("QuestionId", questionId);
        cmdReport.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdReport.Parameters.Add(questionIdPrm);
        daReport.Fill(retVal);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Am not seeing Connection property for Context ? am i missing something ?

Comment: For `DbContext`, it is `context.Database.Connection`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes it can easily be done like this:

```
var table = new DataTable();
using (var ctx = new SomeContext())
{
    var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Col1, Col2 from SomeTable"; 

    cmd.Connection.Open();
    table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
}
```

Comment: nice, how about with parameters?

Comment: @jakotheshadows `cmd` is a `SqlCommand` object so you'd do it as regular e.g. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", whatever);`

Comment: For me it ended up being a DbCommand abstract class which was what was tripping me up at first. But it makes sense if that's true because SqlCommand is derived from DbCommand.

Answer (score 8):

This method uses the connection string from the entity framework to establish an ADO.NET connection, to a MySQL database in this example.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public DataSet GetReportSummary( int RecordID )
{
    var context = new catalogEntities();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using ( MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection( context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString ) )
    {
        using ( MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand( "ReportSummary", connection ) )
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter( cmd );
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add( new MySqlParameter( "@ID", RecordID ) );
            adapter.Fill( ds );
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

By the rule, you shouldn't use a DataSet inside a EF application. But, if you really need to (for instance, to feed a report), that solution should work (it's EF 6 code):

```
    DataSet GetDataSet(string sql, CommandType commandType, Dictionary<string, Object> parameters)
    {
        // creates resulting dataset
        var result = new DataSet();

        // creates a data access context (DbContext descendant)
        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            // creates a Command 
            var cmd = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = commandType;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;

            // adds all parameters
            foreach (var pr in parameters)
            {
                var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
                p.ParameterName = pr.Key;
                p.Value = pr.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }

            try
            {
                // executes
                context.Database.Connection.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                // loop through all resultsets (considering that it's possible to have more than one)
                do
                {
                    // loads the DataTable (schema will be fetch automatically)
                    var tb = new DataTable();
                    tb.Load(reader);
                    result.Tables.Add(tb);

                } while (!reader.IsClosed);
            }
            finally
            {
                // closes the connection
                context.Database.Connection.Close();
            }
        }

        // returns the DataSet
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Very nice. I modified this slightly public static DataSet GetDataSet(this DbContext context, string sql, CommandType commandType, Dictionary<string, Object> parameters)

Answer (score 3):

In my Entity Framework based solution I need to replace one of my Linq queries with sql - for efficiency reasons. 
Also I want my results in a `DataTable` from one stored procedure so that I could create a table value parameter to pass into a second stored procedure. So:

1. I'm using sql
2. I don't want a `DataSet`
3. Iterating an `IEnumerable` probably isn't going to cut it - for efficiency reasons

Also, I am using EF6, so I would prefer `DbContext.SqlQuery` over `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery` as the original poster requested.

However, I found that this just didn't work:

`_Context.Database.SqlQuery<DataTable>(sql, parameters).FirstOrDefault();`

This is my solution. It returns a `DataTable` that is fetched using an ADO.NET `SqlDataReader` - which I believe is faster than a `SqlDataAdapter` on read-only data. It doesn't strictly answer the question because it uses ADO.Net, but it shows how to do that after getting a hold of the connection from the `DbContext`

```
    protected DataTable GetDataTable(string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        //didn't work - table had no columns or rows
        //return Context.Database.SqlQuery<DataTable>(sql, parameters).FirstOrDefault();

        DataTable result = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = Context.Database.Connection as SqlConnection;
        if(conn == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("SqlConnection is invalid for this database");
        }
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                result.Load(reader);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Only one note: Anyone sending in an UPDATE query with parameters - ensure that, of the parameters you send, none are empty strings. If they are, do some checking via code before sending your query to this function, in order to edit that field out of the query and don't send that parameter. Even though my field was not a `NOT NULL` field, it behaved that way when trying to update it with an empty string parameter using this, because the field was specified in the query as receiving an update.

Comment: Anyone sending in an UPDATE command to this function - think again - this is intended for reading data into a DataTable, not for updates

Comment: Yes, that is, reading data FROM a `DataTable`, you meant, yes. I changed it so instead of that whole `ExecuteReader` section, I was doing a `cmd.ExecuteScalar();` to send the update. As a result my comment was probably offbase, as I had made that function a `void` instead of returning a `DataTable`. I also was using this one, too, and I think I got them confused when I made my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to return a DataTable using the EntityFramework is to do the following:

```
MetaTable metaTable = Global.DefaultModel.GetTable("Your EntitySetName");
```

For example:

```
MetaTable metaTable = Global.DefaultModel.GetTable("Employees");
```

Comment: What is this global object? Not sure where you are getting it from. Is it from Web Api 2?

Comment: @Hoppe `MetaTable` and `DefaultModel` (an instance of `MetaModel`) are part of ASP.NET DynamicData, essentially a scaffolding framework. It isn't related to Entity Framework so I don't think this is a useful answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your stored procedure could return a complex type?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2010/01/11/entity-framework-in-net-4.aspx