# How to execute query that Entity Framework doesn't support and get returned data

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, excel-addins

I am using VS2010, C#, .Net Framework 4, (DB provider Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2), to write an add-in for Excel. The main idea is to let a user execute a pre-defined query against the DB, so that the data is pulled into Excel.

Say I have hard-coded queries stored in a table [Queries] in the DB. So I can use Entity Framework to get to the table Queries. These queries listed in the table, could return anything from a single value to multiple records.

I am fairly ignorant regarding Entity Framework. Now, I've read that one can execute T-SQL directly against the database [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/11/07/tip-41-how-to-execute-t-sql-directly-against-the-database.aspx). This has been useful, but I struggle with getting the results back.

```
using (SYMNHM_DEVEntities dataContext = new SYMNHM_DEVEntities())
        {

            var query = "Select [Query Name] from [SYM XLS Queries] where [Query ID] = 2";
            str = dataContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(query) + "";

        }
```

This gives a result of -1, which is then roughly made into a string. Okay, I know this is not good coding, but just see it as an example. How do I get the actual [Query Name] returned?

In this case, it's just a single value, but if the query would return more values (and I might not even know whether it's strings or not) how do I create an appropriate return type?

Comment: In EF ypu would creaye a *Complex Type* and *project the results in it with ExecuteQuery [T] but if you don't wknow what columbs to ezpect this could be fun...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer for the simple example regarding a string:

```
using (MyEntities dataContext = new MyEntities())
    {
      var query = (from q in dataContext.Queries
                     where q.Query_Name == queryName
                     select q.Query).Single();



      queryResults = dataContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>(query);
      List<string> list = new List<string>(queryResults.ToArray<string>());
      return list; }
```

I do not yet have a solution for substituting the string type with something else, although I am looking into the matter of returning a Datatable if the query would have more than one  string result.

Comment: Above you can see that I get the SQL query from another table in the same DB. It is also more appropriate to use the method ExecuteStoreQuery, than ExecuteStoreCommand.

Comment: I ended up using the answer of chuck in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586834/returning-a-datatable-using-entityframe-executestorequery

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good pratice use SQL command directly, why you don't use LINQ ?
In your example you can use:

```
var result = (from q in dataContext.SYMXLSQueries
             where q.ID == 2
             select q.QueryName).ToArray();
```

This return an array of strings (If QueryName is a varchar...)

Comment: I do not use LINQ because I will have hard-coded SQL queries in the [Query] column of my [Queries] table. The above is simply an example of what such a SQL query could possible look like.

Comment: The matter regarding the type of the return values becomes an issue when I have to write code that executes any of these hardcoded SQL queries, and I can not know before hand whether it will return varchar or int, to give the simplest example.