# ExecuteStoreQuery EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

New to params object[]...and  would like to try a suggestion from [Returning a DataTable using Entity Framework ExecuteStoreQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586834/returning-a-datatable-using-entityframe-executestorequery)

How to pass these parameters (`guid gId, string sName`) to a stored procedure using Entity Framework? This is what I want to try, cause, I need to return a data table.

```
public DataTable ExecuteStoreQuery(string commandText, params Object[] parameters)
{
   DataTable retVal = new DataTable();
   retVal = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<DataTable>(commandText, parameters).FirstOrDefault();    
   return retVal;
}
```

Comment: The whole **point** of using Entity Framework is so you **don't have to** mess around with `DataTable` and columns / rows - but instead you can work with nice .NET objects instead! Stop trying to kludge EF into returning a `DataTable` ! Change your design to be able to work with entities (and collections thereof)

Answer (score 3):

As the question/answer you linked to tells you, `ExecuteStoreQuery` returns *entities* - it cannot return a `DataTable`.

You *could* use it to return a collection of entities, then turn that into a `DataTable` using `DataTableExtensions`:

```
public DataTable ExecuteStoreQuery(string commandText, params Object[] parameters)
{
   DataTable retVal;

   var entities = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<MyEntity>(commandText, parameters)
                          .Take(1); // use `Take` instead of `First` to keep it as a collection
   retVal = entities.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable();
   return retVal;
}
```

As far as `params` goes, that just lets you string values together in your method call instead of packaging them up in an `object[]`:

```
DataTable dt = ExecuteStoreQuery("SELECT * FROM...", guid, sName);
```

Answer (score -5):

```
The idea of params (which always has to be the last decalared parameter in a function can be unlimited for example

Function Foo(string s,params Object[] alist)
{
    //whatever
}

Cats cat = new Cats();//I put an object here because cat is an object, if it was ints they would all have to be ints
Foo("ok",cat);
Foo("ok", cat,cat,cat,cat,cat,cat);

are both valid
```

is the idea but your going to want to pass SQL params so...

```
            dt = ExecuteStoreQuery("INSERT INTO STATUS(ITEMTYPE,PRODESC) values(@ITEMTYPE,'@PRODESC')",new SqlParameter("@ITEMTYPE", 2),new SqlParameter("@PRODESC", "Obama sucks"));
```

or more liner for me so I can see better

```
        object[] obj;
        obj[0] = new SqlParameter("@ITEMTYPE", 2);
        obj[1] = new SqlParameter("@PRODESC", "Obama sucks");
        dt = ExecuteStoreQuery("INSERT INTO STATUS(ITEMTYPE,PRODESC) values(@ITEMTYPE,'@PRODESC')",obj);
```