# LINQ Not In, so that I can use in a Merge

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have this, one datatable and one entity class that I can convert to a datatable.

```
UC010_WizardStepBusinessParkDataSet dataSet = new UC010_WizardStepBusinessParkDataSet();
        View_BuildingModule_UC010_BusinessPark_Wizard_GetBusinessParkData vwBusPark = new View_BuildingModule_UC010_BusinessPark_Wizard_GetBusinessParkData();
```

I want to return with a LINQ query the ones that are in vwBusPark that are not in dataset.BusinessPark.

I was trying something like the following but I am stuck:

```
   var query = dataSet.BusinessPark.Where(entry => !vwBusPark.toDataTable().AsEnumerable().Contains(entry.BusinessParkID));
```

It says:

Error   1   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, TSource)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. C:\BITProjects\TeamSystem\luival\refm\DEV\BuildingModule\Business\UC010_BusinessPark_Wizard\BusinessParkWizardBL.cs 42  62  Ceusters.REFM.BuildingModule.Business

Comment: `ToDataTable().AsEnumerable()` will return a sequence of *rows* - potentially with several columns - which column are you interested in?

Comment: BusinessParkId, can you help me correct the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var vwBusParkIDs = vwBusPark.toDataTable().AsEnumerable().Select(r => Convert.ToInt32( r["BusinessParkId"]));
var query = dataSet.BusinessPark.Where(entry => !vwBusParkIDs.Contains(entry.BusinessParkID));
```

Comment: 3 exceptions: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'BusinessParkID' and no extension method 'BusinessParkID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found

Comment: Error 2 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow.BusinessParkID>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'

Comment: Error 3 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow.BusinessParkID>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Luis See my edit. I've used Covert.ToInt32() for BusinessParkId but if that's not accurate, use the right conversion method and see if it helps.

Comment: at least it compiled, now I need to be able to use the results of query, in the Merge method?? any idea?    if (vwBusPark.Query.Load())
                dataSet.BusinessPark.Merge(query???, true, System.Data.MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);

Comment: @Luis I'm not very familiar with DataTable.Merge() but it definitely does not take IEnumerable for a parameter. You can look into converting IEnumerable to DataTable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253725/convert-ienumerable-to-datatable and then maybe use the result to Merge.