# Linq C# Groupby on datatable

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-dataset

I would like to write a `Linq` query to apply group-by on `DataTable`, which outputs the result as a `DataTable`.

I tried this code, which returns a result as `var` type, but I want the result in `DataTable`

```
var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<DateTime>("ExpDate").Year into grp
            select new
            {
                Years = grp.Key,
                RSF = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("SpaceRSF"))
            };
```

Please could you assist me in finding a proper answer.

Comment: what do you mean to say " i want the result in datatable"?

Comment: I mean to say DataTable dts = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<DateTime>("ExpDate").Year into grp
       something like this not as var type, should be as DataTable type

Comment: Try that http://stackoverflow.com/a/1253737/1744834 if you want DataTable and not IEnumerable

Answer (score 2):

Look at [How to: Implement CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) - this topic describes how to implement two custom CopyToDataTable extension methods that accept a generic parameter T of a type other than DataRow.

Just use code from that article (`ObjectShredder<T>`) to achieve following result:

```
DataTable table = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so according to this

```
select new
            {
                Years = grp.Key,
                RSF = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("SpaceRSF"))
            };
```

`code which return result as var type` effectively returns collection of objects having two properties: `Years` and `RSF`.
If you want to have datatable instead, then write the code that puts all the data into the datatable. Basically, it might look similarly as following:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Years");
table.Columns.Add("RSF");
foreach(var item in query)
{
     table.Add(item.Years, items.RSF)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for answer, i have done same as you suggest but I think here in this case we may run extra foreach loop i want to avoid that foreach and get output directly as datatable if possible