# LINQ - Return rows with all columns of a table based on multiple distinct columns

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table,

```
**Matter No      Client No    Client Name  Invoice No  Invoice Date    Invoice Amt**

1111-0001          1111          ABC            101       01/01/2013       100.00 
1111-0001          1111          ABC            102       02/01/2013       200.00
1111-0001          1111          ABC            103       03/01/2013       300.00
1111-0001          1111          ABC            104       04/01/2013       400.00
1111-0001          1112          DEF            105       05/01/2013       500.00
1111-0001          1113          GHI            106       06/01/2013       600.00
```

Based on above scenario, I wish to return all the columns but DISTINCT ROWS based on Columns - Matter No and Client No.  i.e.  I need to see 3 rows as output:

```
**Matter No      Client No    Client Name  Invoice No  Invoice Date    Invoice Amt**

1111-0001          1111          ABC            101       01/01/2013       100.00 
1111-0001          1112          DEF            105       05/01/2013       500.00
1111-0001          1113          GHI            106       06/01/2013       600.00
```

How I can achieve this in LINQ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dó you have some c# code to og with your question? :-) what have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

```
from x in table
group x by new {x.MatterNo, x.ClientNo}
into mygroup
select mygroup.First();
```

Or if you prefer this syntax

```
list.DistinctBy(x => new {x.MatterNo, x.ClientNo});
```

If you're not dealing with a list you can try

```
from DataRow drow in dtable.Rows
group drow by new {MatterNo = drow["Matter No"], ClientNo = drow["Client No"]}
into myGroup
select myGroup.First();
```

Comment: thanks but column name is [Matter No] and [Client No].  Above query is not recognizing x.matterno and x.clientNo.  It says System.Data.DataRow doesn't contain definition for x.MatterNo

Comment: @prafullashimpi I'm changed it, does the last example bring you any closer?

Comment: goup -> group? Typo, I'm assuming

Comment: thanks again. Now I am receiving an error "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access." for the statement **{drow["Matter No"], drow["Client No"]}**.  I added missing 'r' to the group.

Comment: Because it's not valid syntax for creating an anonymous type. Try: new { MatterNo = drow["Matter No"], ClientNo = drow["Client No"]}

Comment: I am trying to return this result as data table, if possible, but getting error as ** "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Data.DataTable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" **  The query I am writing is:   DataTable dtRows  =  from DataRow drow in dt.Rows
                                 group drow by new { MatterNo = drow["Matter No"], ClientNo = drow["Client No"] }
                                    into myGroup
                                    select myGroup.First  ;

Comment: @prafullashimpi That's a separate issue, but here is a solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/2263691/103959

Comment: @Jean-Bernard Pellerin, thanks for your help.  I tried a lot to cast, still I am unable to compile this,  will it possible to help me with  a LINQ query returning result set as datatable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataTable result = dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("COLUMN NAME"))
                     .Select(x => x.First()).CopyToDataTable();
```