# vb.net - multiplying values from datatable

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, datatable, multiplication

I'm working in vb.net and in my program i have two datatables. What i want is to multiply quantity for some IZ in the second datatable with the quantity for the same IZ from first datatable. I want to do that for every IZ.

For example for IZ12554 it would be like 1*460=460 and 0,0025*460=1,15; for IZ10836 it would be 3*2000=6000; 1*2000=2000; 1*2000=2000 etc, and write those results in datatable 3.

`DATATABLE 1`

`Capacity    IZ   Quantity  ID    Document`

`-------------------------------------------`

`DM00006   IZ12554   460    20   PDN00084625`

`DM00007   IZ10836   2000    1   PDN00084983`

`DM00010   IZ12641   25200   1   PDN00084997`
 
`DM00011   IZ03941   940     1   PDN00084639`
 
`DM00087   IZ15137   50     12   PDN00084904`

`....`

`....`

`DATATABLE 2`

`IZ         MA     Quantity    Unit`

`----------------------------------`

`IZ12554  MA06196     1        KOS`

`IZ12554  MA05545     0,0025   KOS`

`IZ10836  MA06199     3        KOS`

`IZ10836  MA06197     1        KOS`

`IZ10836  MA00892     1        kos`

`IZ12641  MA06199     1        KOS`

`IZ12641  MA32200     0,04     m`

`IZ03941  MA07639     0,0025   KOS`

`IZ03941  MA00896     0,295    M`

`IZ03941  MA06200     1        KOS`

`IZ03941  MA00892     1        kos`

`IZ15137  MA06200     1        KOS`

`IZ15137  MA00557     0,0025   KOS`

`IZ15137  MA00897     0,295    M`

`...`

`...`



`DATATABLE 3 - RESULTS`

`IZ         MA     Quantity    Unit`

`----------------------------------`

`IZ12554  MA06196     460      KOS`

`IZ12554  MA05545     1,15     KOS`

`IZ10836  MA06199     6000     KOS`

`IZ10836  MA06197     2000     KOS`

`IZ10836  MA00892     2000     kos`

`IZ12641  MA06199     25200    KOS`

`IZ12641  MA32200     1000,8   m`

`IZ03941  MA07639     2,35     KOS`

`IZ03941  MA00896     277,3    M`

`IZ03941  MA06200     940      KOS`

`IZ03941  MA00892     940      kos`

`IZ15137  MA06200     50       KOS`

`IZ15137  MA00557     0,125    KOS`

`IZ15137  MA00897     14,75    M`

`...`

`...`

I searched for answer, but still don't know how to work with datatables, i'm a complete beginner at programming...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can easily find tutorials on how to complete a select statement and joint tables through the web...

Comment: I agree with @Fjodr this would most likely be easier if you wrote your initial SQL Query to do a join and multiply for you, prior to creating the datatable.  I would also venture that it would be much faster as well.

Comment: Downvote is a bit harsh in my opinion. He might be doing it at runtime (DataTable being populated by user input or some file reading etc.) instead of doing it directly against a SQL table (thus not having the option of using `SELECT`), so LINQ may better suit his needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something similar to this:

```
DataTable DataTable3 = new DataTable();

DataColumn myDataColumn;
myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
myDataColumn.ColumnName = "IZ";
DataTable3.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

DataColumn myDataColumn;
myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
myDataColumn.ColumnName = "MA";
DataTable3.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

DataColumn myDataColumn;
myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Sum_QTY";
DataTable3.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);
//ADD More columns to DataTable Here

foreach(DataRow row in DataTable1.Rows){
 foreach(DataRow row2 in DataTable2.Rows){
   if (row["IZ"].ToString()==row2["IZ"].ToString()){
    //Row3 is the row from Table 3
    row3 = DataTable3.NewRow();

    row3["IZ"]=row["IZ"].ToString();
    row3["MA"]=row2["MA"].ToString();
    row3["Sum_QTY"]=row2["Quantity"]*row["Quantity"];
    //ADD calculations here and add them to row3
    DataTable3.Rows.Add(row3);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I get error when i put your code in: "System.ArgumentException: Column 'IZ' does not belong to table"
But i created column "IZ" in datatable3... what could be wrong here?

Comment: It sounds like that column doesn't exist. Did you create the Datatable before trying to do that?

Comment: Sorry my bad - i didn't create datatable3 at all, i just created Griedview with column "IZ", that's probably not enough?

Comment: I edited to include creating a sample DataTable3 if you wanted to look.

Comment: Wow thanks! But now i only have column "IZ" in datatable3... i also want column "MA" (with all MA's) and column "SUM QTY" with sum quantity in datatable3. How can that be done?

Comment: Added that to the post. Might not be right. General logic to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments to the question suggest, doing this in the database may be more efficient, but you can use [LINQ to DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to join the data and perform the calculations:

```vb
Dim result =
    From r2 In dt2.AsEnumerable()
    Join r1 In dt1.AsEnumerable() On r2.Field(Of String)("IZ") Equals r1.Field(Of String)("IZ")
    Select
        IZ = r2.Field(Of String)("IZ"),
        MA = r2.Field(Of String)("MA"),
        Quantity = r2.Field(Of Decimal)("Quantity") * r1.Field(Of Integer)("Quantity"),
        Unit = r2.Field(Of String)("Unit")
```

This gives you an `IEnumerable` of anonymous types containing the results you want.  I don't know of a built-in way to convert that back to a `DataTable` (if you even need to), but you can do it with a little reflection.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1253725/2278086) for more details, but something like this should work:

```vb
<Extension>
Function ToDataTable(Of T)(items As IEnumerable(Of T)) As DataTable
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    Dim props = GetType(T).GetProperties()
    For Each prop In props
        Dim dc = dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType)
    Next
    For Each item In items
        Dim dr = dt.NewRow()
        For Each prop In props
            dr(prop.Name) = prop.GetValue(item)
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
    Return dt
End Function
```

You can then:

```vb
Dim dt3 = result.ToDataTable()
' or ToDataTable(result) if you don't make it an extension method
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried that but i get error in Line 71 (equal sign is underline in my application): 

Compiler Error Message: BC30201: Expression expected.
Source Error:
Line 69: 
Line 70: 
Line 71:         Dim result =
Line 72:         From r2 In dt2.AsEnumerable()
Line 73:         Join r1 In dt1.AsEnumerable() On r2.Field(Of String)("IZ") Equals r1.Field(Of String)("IZ")
 
Is there some code missing or what? It may be stupid question but i'm really a beginner in this...

Comment: @kb2487 What version of Visual Studio are you using?  I can't recreate that error here, but older versions of the VB.NET compiler (pre-VS2010, I think) required a continuation character at the end of each line of a multi-line statement - the `_` character.  Also check that you have a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` (although I think that would be a different error).  LINQ was added in VS2008, so before that this will not work at all.  That's about all I can guess with the given information.  Sorry.