# Guidance for Crystal Report data filling From WCF Rest Service

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, rest, crystal-reports

I am working on `WCF` Rest Service With `EnitityFrameWork` .now I m bulding `C#` Winform Client, at client end I need to show some reports with result returning from WCF rest Service. Im new to Crystal Reports, I have Installed SAP Crystal reports with Visual Studio 2013. But I dont know how to work with this type of architecture? Please guide me how I can accomplished My Task Effciently, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Crystal report runtime only works with Datasets/DataTables. So you need to take your result data from your rest service [create a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253725/convert-ienumerable-to-datatable) and bind that to the report.

```
var iEnumerableFromWCFService = callYourWcfService();
DataTable dt = iEnumerableFromWCFService.ToDataTable<YourDataType>();
// or write your own method to createDataSetFromCollection(dataFromWcfService);
report.SetDataSource(dt);
```

Alternatively, you can get Crystal to get it's data directly from the database without your entity framework data.

Comment: thats looks fine,please also guide me to how I can design reports with DB connection? how I can Start Designing Crystal reports in Visual Studio 2013,I have Installed SAP crystal Reports for 2013, Im nill in designing Crystal reports for client end. in Wcf Architecure

Comment: The WCF aspect of your requirement is irrelevant. You need a way to export the dataset as xml or xsd: 
    string filename="Schema.xml";

    // Write the schema to the file.
    thisDataSet.WriteXmlSchema(filename);, then in the report wizard, point to this xml dataset to use as a datasource

Comment: My forms are ready they are doing CRUD by WCF. For reports I need to populate it from WCF, Wcf returns Custom DTO class. I there any way to convert DTO class to Dataset? so that I can Fill Report

Comment: I have done by returing List from Service and  setting report Source as list. It  shows the data on report but only master object from list . it not showing detail objects. I follow example of link below
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/371018/Create-Crystal-Report-Document