# Revisiting IEnumerable to DataTable extension method -- Issue with strings

Tags: c#, string, datatable, ienumerable, extension-methods

I am working on a "ToDataTable()" that I can use on IEnumerable. Lots of examples of that, such as here: [Convert IEnumerable to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253725/convert-ienumerable-to-datatable). DataTables are desirable for me because I am coming from a Foxpro realm where we are used to cursors. So, I dig DataTables because they are relatively simple, easy to work with, and can house decent column meta-data. And I've already got a bunch of code that can display them nicely (with sort and filter grid headers), export to Excel, etc.

Someone made a really good comment on the thread I linked to above: "*This doesn't work if the type is string as the properties are chars and length but the get value then tries to put the full string into the char column.*"

Problem is, certain things fit the extension method call (like a one-dimensional array of strings) but then throw errors when the conversion takes place. I wrote an extension method that adds IsValueType() to the mix, but the problem is that returns false for strings. Finally, I added two kludges: a parameter to force the item in the sequence to be treated as a value, and to treat the item in the sequence as a value if it is found to be of type "String".

Is there a better way of doing this, or are strings just an odd man out due to their unique breed of typing and reflection results? The following code works with every IEnumerable I can think of, and it works with one-dimensional arrays for all DataTable column types except for string (well, it works for strings with the hard-coded kludge, but would error out otherwise). It's not a big deal to hard-code the string scenario, I just wish there was a more elegant way to do this. Any thoughts?

```
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string tableName = "", bool treatItemAsValue = false)
    {
        // We want a single extension method that can take in an enumerable sequence (such as a LINQ query)
        // and return the result as a DataTable. We want this to be a one stop shop for converting
        // various objects into DataTable format, as DataTables are a nice parallel to Foxpro cursors.
        if (items == null) { return null; }
        Type itemType = typeof(T);
        bool typeIsNullable = itemType.IsGenericType && typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>));
        string itemTypeName = "";
        bool typeIsValue = false;
        Type itemUnderlyingType = itemType;
        if (typeIsNullable)
        {
            // Type of enumerable item is nullable, so we need to find its base type.
            itemUnderlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(itemType);
        }
        typeIsValue = itemUnderlyingType.IsValueType;
        itemTypeName = itemUnderlyingType.Name;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn col = null;
        if ((treatItemAsValue) || (itemTypeName == "String"))
        {
            // We have been asked to treat the item in the sequence as a value, of the items
            // in the sequence are strings. Strings are NOT considered a value type in regards
            // to IsValueType(), but when item values are assessed, it will be the value
            // of the string that tries to pull in.
            typeIsValue = true;
        }
        if (itemTypeName == "DataRow")
        {
            // Special case. If our enumerable type is DataRow, then we can utilize a more appropriate
            // (built-in) extension method to convert enumerable DataRows to a DataTable.
            dt = ((IEnumerable<DataRow>)items).CopyToDataTable();
        }
        else
        {
            // We must have an enumerable sequence/collection of some other type, possibly anonymous.
            // Get properties of the enumerable to add as columns to the data table.
            if (typeIsValue)
            {
                // Our enumerable items are of a value type (e.g. integers in a one-dimensional array).
                col = dt.Columns.Add();
                col.AllowDBNull = typeIsNullable;
                col.ColumnName = itemTypeName;
                col.DataType = itemUnderlyingType;
                // Now walk through the enumeration and add rows to our data table (single values).
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The type should be something we can walk through the properties of in order to
                // generate properly named and typed columns of our DataTable.
                PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                foreach (var prop in props)
                {
                    Type propType = prop.PropertyType;
                    // Is it a nullable type? Get the underlying type.
                    if (propType.IsGenericType && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
                    {
                        propType = new NullableConverter(propType).UnderlyingType;
                    }
                    dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name, propType);
                }
                // Now walk through the enumeration and add rows to our data table.
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    var values = new object[props.Length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                    {
                        values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(values);
                }
            }
        }
        // Give the DataTable a reasonable name.
        if (tableName.Length == 0)
        {
            if (typeof(T).IsAnonymous())
            {
                // Anonymous types have really goofy names, so there is no use using that as table name.
                tableName = "Anonymous";
            }
            else
            {
                // This is NOT an anonymous type, so we can use the type name as table name.
                tableName = typeof(T).Name;
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you writing one yourself when, as you mentioned, there are lots of existing implementations available?

Comment: Because they are incomplete. For example, if you pass a one-dimensional array of strings to most implementations out there, it will error out. That's why I am asking. I want to write a fully comprehensive ToDataTable() that can handle anything that gets thrown its way. So, I modified some existing solutions to get closer to that goal. I'm just asking if there is a better way to handle the string case that I might be missing. (And I would always have to write one myself, even if by "write" it means to cut and paste -- there is no "built-in" ToDataTable() method that works across the board.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no responses except a comment that pretty much missed the point, so I'll just post what I ended up with. This final version also accounts for items with no properties (such as "Object" itself), and does some better handing of null items/values:

```
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string tableName = "", bool treatItemAsValue = false)
    {
        // We want a single extension method that can take in an enumerable sequence (such as a LINQ query)
        // and return the result as a DataTable. We want this to be a one stop shop for converting
        // various objects into DataTable format, as DataTables are a nice parallel to Foxpro cursors.
        if (items == null) { return null; }
        Type itemType = typeof(T);
        bool typeIsNullable = itemType.IsGenericType && typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>));
        string itemTypeName = "";
        bool typeIsValue = false;
        Type itemUnderlyingType = itemType;
        if (typeIsNullable)
        {
            // Type of enumerable item is nullable, so we need to find its base type.
            itemUnderlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(itemType);
        }
        typeIsValue = itemUnderlyingType.IsValueType;
        itemTypeName = itemUnderlyingType.Name;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn col = null;
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if ((treatItemAsValue) || (itemTypeName == "String") || (props.Length == 0))
        {
            // We have been asked to treat the item in the sequence as a value, or the items
            // in the sequence is a string which cannot be "flattened" properly by analyzing properties.
            // OR, the type has no properties to put on display, so we should just use the item directly.
            // (like the base "Object" type).
            typeIsValue = true;
        }
        if (itemTypeName == "DataRow")
        {
            // Special case. If our enumerable type is DataRow, then we can utilize a more appropriate
            // (built-in) extension method to convert enumerable DataRows to a DataTable.
            dt = ((IEnumerable<DataRow>)items).CopyToDataTable();
        }
        else
        {
            // We must have an enumerable sequence/collection of some other type, possibly anonymous.
            // Get properties of the enumerable to add as columns to the data table.
            if (typeIsValue)
            {
                // Our enumerable items are of a value type (e.g. integers in a one-dimensional array).
                col = dt.Columns.Add();
                // Whether or not the type is nullable, the value might be null (e.g. for type "Object").
                col.AllowDBNull = true;
                col.ColumnName = itemTypeName;
                col.DataType = itemUnderlyingType;
                // Now walk through the enumeration and add rows to our data table (single values).
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The type should be something we can walk through the properties of in order to
                // generate properly named and typed columns of our DataTable.
                foreach (var prop in props)
                {
                    Type propType = prop.PropertyType;
                    // Is it a nullable type? Get the underlying type.
                    if (propType.IsGenericType && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
                    {
                        propType = new NullableConverter(propType).UnderlyingType;
                    }
                    dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name, propType);
                }
                // Now walk through the enumeration and add rows to our data table.
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        // Can only add an item as a row if it is not null.
                        var values = new object[props.Length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                        {
                            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(values);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Give the DataTable a reasonable name.
        if (tableName.Length == 0)
        {
            if (typeof(T).IsAnonymous())
            {
                // Anonymous types have really goofy names, so there is no use using that as table name.
                tableName = "Anonymous";
            }
            else
            {
                // This is NOT an anonymous type, so we can use the type name as table name.
                tableName = typeof(T).Name;
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Hope someone finds this useful...