# Increment column value in datatable if duplicate row is found

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am trying to summarize some data in a data table, what I am attempting to do is to sum the total quantity of duplicate rows found.

My data table looks like this.

```
|ForeName|SurName|Quantity|
|Dave    |Smith  | 10000  |
|Dave    |Smith  | 20000  |
|Dave    |Smith  | 30000  |
|John    |Peacock| 10000  |
```

I want to summarize this data to look like this.

```
|ForeName|SurName|Quantity|
|Dave    |Smith  | 60000  |
|John    |Peacock| 10000  |
```

At the moment I am searching for duplicates in the data table

```
Dim duplicates = From rows In dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(r) New With {Key .a = r("ForeName"), Key .b = r("SurName")}).Where(Function(gr) gr.Count() > 1).ToList()
```

However where to proceed from here I am unsure, has anyone ever came across a scenario like this and able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you wanting to change the datatable contents or just report on it?

Comment: Hi Plutonix thanks for replying. I just want to report on it, I was thinking maybe I could build a new datatable with the summary data, it was my intent to try and find any duplicates then sum the total of them, but I'm not sure the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the rows by name(s) or ID; use the name/ID as the identifier in a new anon type, and a Count/Total or Quantity property to collect the `Sum` of the Quantity:

```
Dim duplicates = myDT.AsEnumerable().
                 GroupBy(Function(r) New With {Key .Item = r.Field(Of String)("Name")}).
                 Select(Function(g) New With {Key .Name = g.Key.Item,
                                              Key .Count = g.Count,
                           Key .Total = g.Sum(Function(s) s.Field(Of Int32)("Quantity"))}).
                                      OrderByDescending(Function(j) j.Total).
                                      ToList()
```

For "fun" it also counts the number of source/group rows and orders them by the total.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind that the output is anonymous types instead of DataRows, you could use a LINQ query like this:

```
Dim summary = 
    From r In dt.AsEnumerable()
    Group By ForeName = r.Field(Of String)("ForeName"), SurName = r.Field(Of String)("SurName") Into Group
    Select ForeName, SurName, Quantity = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("Quantity"))
```

```
ForeName | SurName | Quantity
---------+---------+---------
Dave     | Smith   |    60000
John     | Peacock |    10000
```

You could use the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253725/convert-ienumerable-to-datatable) to convert it back into a DataTable, if needed.

Adding the count, like in [Plutonix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38981037/2278086) would simply mean adding `Group.Count` to the `Select` clause:

```
Dim summary = 
    From r In dt.AsEnumerable()
    Group By ForeName = r.Field(Of String)("ForeName"), SurName = r.Field(Of String)("SurName") Into Group
    Select ForeName, SurName, Group.Count, Quantity = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("Quantity"))
```

```
ForeName | SurName | Count | Quantity
---------+---------+-------+---------
Dave     | Smith   |     3 |    60000
John     | Peacock |     1 |    10000
```