# Specify Which Columns Are In A Datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a stored procedure that returns extra columns.  I don't have control of the stored procedure.  I would like to use the following form to generate my worksheet:

```
ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light8)
```

How can I output just the columns I want?

I tried to figure out a Linq query but the problem is that the column names are inaccessible so I can't specify which columns I would like.

```
        SqlConnection cx = new SqlConnection(util.GetConnectionString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredRept", cx);
        cmd.CommandType =  CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter ta = new SqlDataAdapter();
        ta.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ta.Fill(dt);


        FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("c:\temp");
        ExcelPackage epp = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
        var ws = epp.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("WS");

        // here is where I would like to copy certain columns off into another data table but I haven't been able to figure out how  

        ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light8);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dump those `DataTable`s! But not like LINQPad `.Dump()`. Just dump. Don't use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If removing some columns from the table is the only problem, that is easy to resolve. Try something like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("First", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Second", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Third", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Fourth", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Fifth", typeof(string));

for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add($"First {i}", $"Second {i}", $"Third {i}",$"Fourth {i}",$"Fifth {i}");
}

//dt.Dump();//If you have linqpad this is handy to dump table to output

//REMOVE THE COLUMNS. 
dt.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
dt.Columns.RemoveAt(2); 

//dt.Dump();//again in linqpad this dumps table with remaining 3 columns
```

You can use following method to find column by name and remove it:

```
var col=dt.Columns["Second"];
dt.Columns.Remove(col);
```

Here is linq query to get list with desired columns.

```
var lq = (from DataRow r in dt.Rows
         select new { First = r[0], Second=r[1], Third=r["Fifth"]}
         ).ToList();
lq.Dump();
```

Note how you can use both column index or name to get value from row object.

Answer (score 2):

Can you load your spreadsheet with `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `DataTable`? If so:

```
var someColumns = dt
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new
    {
        When    = row.Field<DateTime>("When"),
        What    = row.Field<string>("What"),
        HowMany = row.Field<int>("ColumnNameInDatabase"),
    });
```

If you need `DataTable`, you can convert `IEnumerable` to it via any method, like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253725/convert-ienumerable-to-datatable).

### BUT

Frankly, I answered your problem, but IMO you've a greater problem at hand, which is using those antiquated `DataTable` objects instead of `IEnumerable<T>`. If you consider, for example, `Dapper` library, you could do this:

```
util.GetConnectionString()
    .Query("StoredRept", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure) // Extension method from Dapper
    .Select(dyn => new
    {
        When    = (DateTime)dyn.When,
        What    = (string)dyn.What,
        HowMany = (int)dyn.ColumnNameInDatabase
    })
```

I see you're using `EPPlus` library for Excel manipulation. It can load `IEnumerable<T>` data, you are not restricted to `DataTable`.

Comment: I'll have to look at Dapper :)  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Wait -- Dapper can divine the field names from stored procedures?  That is so amazing!!!   Delayed reaction there :)

Comment: That's not exactly it - no framework can divine ;) `Query` downloads an `IEnumerable` of `dynamic` objects, meaning that is the field exists (= the column name in stored procedure exists with that exact name), it will work, but if it doesn't, you'll get an exception - and also you don't get the Intellisense. That's how `dynamic` works in .NET, this is not Dapper specific. Please also note that there are overloads for `Query` -
 `Query<T>`, where `T` is a class defining columns which will get returned from your stored procedure. You get Intellisense, but need to maintain and update this class.