# Dynamic Left join 2 datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 C# datatable:

Datatable A:

| id | Name | Age | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Pauls | 22 | 170 |
| 02 | Sam | 20 | 175 |
| 03 | Mike | 20 | 175 |
| 04 | Jame | 23 | 180 |

Datatable B:

| id | Height | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 175 | 23 |
| 02 | 190 | 21 |

The question here is how could I get this output by join 2 table A & B by id and get output datatable using Linq in C# OutputTable:

| id | Name | Age | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Pauls | 23(value in table B) | 175 (value in table B) |
| 02 | Sam | 21(value in table B) | 190 (value in table B) |
| 03 | Mike | 20 | 175 |
| 04 | Jame | 23 | 180 |

My code here:

```
var results = from ta in tableA.AsEnumerable()
  join tb in tableB.AsEnumerable on ta["id"] equals tb["id"]
  select new 
  {
    ta["id"],
    ta["Name"],
    tb["Age"],
    tb["Height"]
    };
```

My output so far (not what I expected):

| id | Name | Age | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Pauls | 23(value in table B) | 175 (value in table B) |
| 02 | Sam | 21(value in table B) | 190 (value in table B) |

P/s: above table is just an example data, true data is bigger

Answer (score 2):

INNER JOIN works as filter if record not found on the right side. You have to use LEFT JOIN here, which is implemented in LINQ as GroupJoin with SelectMany:

```cs
var results = from ta in tableA
    join tb in tableB on ta.id equals tb.id into g
    from tb in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        ta.id,
        ta.Name,
        Age = tb != null ? tb.Age : ta.Age,
        Height = tb != null ? tb.Height : ta.Height,
    };
```

Comment: and how to add results for output table?

Comment: I didn't get question. LINQ query selects data but not add something.

Comment: My expected output is an datatable so please help!!!

Comment: Check this [Miscrosoft sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/implement-copytodatatable-where-type-not-a-datarow?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this:

```
  var results = from ta in tableA
  join tb in tableB on ta.id equals tb.id into gj
  from subTableA in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new 
  {
    id = ta.id,
    Name = ta.Name,
    Age = (subTableA == null ? ta.Age : tb.Age + "(value in table B)"),
    Height = (subTableA == null ? ta.Height : tb.Height + "(value in table B)") 
    };
```

Here is some page about left join using Entity Framework - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Idea is to introduce row 'from subTableA in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()' in order to get all rows from the join, even those which don't have matching value in second table.

Comment: thanks for your help. But could you help me on adding the results into datatable for the output?

Comment: not sure if I understand, you want to create new database table from the result table?

Comment: My expected output like I asked in question is a Datatable with data is output joined result

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to get back a `DataTable` from your LINQ query. However, LINQ returns an `IEnumerable<T>` or an `IQueryable<T>` if you're querying a database.

If you want a `DataTable`, you'll need some additional code. I suggest you refer to the top answer on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253725/convert-ienumerable-to-datatable), which provides a solution for converting an `IEnumerable` to a `DataTable`.

Comment: I'm really appreciate for your help, but my problems here is the output result as IEnumerable output is missing some column (ex: A Datatable contain 5 rows, B DataTable contain 2 rows, after joined by id, the result only have 2 rows from joined result of A and B)