# How to Add Rows from DataTable to DataGridView That Is Already Populated Data in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview, dapper

I tried it has not worked therefore it does not add rows in the DataGridView please guide me. Is the code I applied something wrong please guide

Thanks

Below is the code I used

```
 Dim pservice As New personService
    Public dt As New DataTable()
 Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(invono As personmaster)
        Me.New
        DataGridView1.DataSource = pservice.GetPersondetailbyinvono(invono.Invono)
        TextBox1.Text = invono.Invono
        dt.Columns.AddRange({
  New DataColumn("ID", GetType(Integer)),
  New DataColumn("Invono", GetType(String)),
  New DataColumn("NamePerson", GetType(String)),
  New DataColumn("Age", GetType(Integer)),
  New DataColumn("Job", GetType(String))})
    End Sub
  Private Sub BTNADD_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNADD.Click
        dt.Rows.Add(dt.Rows.Count + 1, txtInvono.Text, txtNameperson.Text, txtAge.Text, txtJob.Text)
    End Sub
Public Function GetPersondetailbyinvono(ByVal Invno As String) As IEnumerable(Of persondetail)
        Dim sql = $"SELECT * FROM PersonDetail WHERE Invono = '{Invno}'"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of persondetail)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
```

[image: VIEW]

Comment: How about you describe the actual problem? Just saying that it didn't work is of little value if you don't explain what you actually expect and how what happened differs from that. Please visit the Help Centre to learn how to ask a question properly.

Comment: Why would you be seeing the DataSource twice? The grid will display whatever is in the list you provide. If you assign a second list, it completely replaces the first list. If you expect to add rather than replace, you need to add to the list that is already bound.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Thank you for your reply.  `How about you describe the actual problem?`  sorry I didn't tell you the problem and now I have updated the description and  it does not add rows in the DataGridView

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `Why would you be seeing the DataSource twice? The grid will display whatever is in the list you provide. If you assign a second list, it completely replaces the first list. If you expect to add rather than replace, you need to add to the list that is already bound.`  You are right, I should have used my source once according to the first one. Please Guide me

Comment: Create a list, bind it to the grid, make your changes to that list. That's it, that's all. If you want that list to be a DataTable, use a DataTable. If you want it to be something else, use dinnertime else. We have no idea what your service method returns because you haven't told us. Your question still lacks significant detail.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `We have no idea what your service method returns because you haven't told us. Your question still lacks significant detail.` for this I updated the code in the post about the method . `If you want that list to be a DataTable, use a DataTable.` This means that there are 2 options, it can be in list and datatable. Please guide me

Comment: A DataTable is a list. If I meant List(Of T) then that's what I would have written. A list is conceptually just anything with multiple items. There are countless various implementations, of which a DataTable is one.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , means I have to make the list into a datatable please guide me

Answer (score 0):

as per link [a link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/f4d8d416-2ee3-4d76-9757-0698bdff87e9/add-rows-in-to-bounded-datagridview-vbnet?forum=winformsdatacontrols)!
as per link [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253725/convert-ienumerable-to-datatable)!

As per the link above I got a solution.

```
Dim pservice As New personService
    Public dt As New DataTable()
 Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
Public Function ToDataTable(Of T)(ByVal items As IEnumerable(Of T)) As DataTable
        Dim tb = New DataTable(GetType(T).Name)
        Dim props() As PropertyInfo = GetType(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance)
        For Each prop In props
            tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, If(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType), prop.PropertyType))
        Next prop
        For Each item In items
            Dim values = New Object(props.Length - 1) {}
            For i = 0 To props.Length - 1
                values(i) = props(i).GetValue(item, Nothing)
            Next i

            tb.Rows.Add(values)
        Next item

        Return tb
    End Function
    Public Sub New(invono As personmaster)
        Me.New
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ToDataTable(pservice.GetPersondetailbyinvono(invono.Invono))
        TextBox1.Text = invono.Invono
        dt.Columns.AddRange({
  New DataColumn("ID", GetType(Integer)),
  New DataColumn("Invono", GetType(String)),
  New DataColumn("NamePerson", GetType(String)),
  New DataColumn("Age", GetType(Integer)),
  New DataColumn("Job", GetType(String))})
    End Sub
  Private Sub BTNADD_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNADD.Click
        Dim dt = CType(datagridview1.DataSource, datatable)
dt.Rows.Add(dt.Rows.Count + 1, txtInvono.Text, txtNameperson.Text, txtAge.Text, txtJob.Text)
    End Sub
Public Function GetPersondetailbyinvono(ByVal Invno As String) As IEnumerable(Of persondetail)
        Dim sql = $"SELECT * FROM PersonDetail WHERE Invono = '{Invno}'"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of persondetail)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
```